# Rails - Get all keys from params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

In order to improve my `Rails` app security, I want to know how to get **all** keys from a parametters hash

hash example :

```
params = 
{"id"=>23, "name"=>"test", "infos"=>{"data"=>"er323e3ee23reQir", "signed"=>true}}
```

if I do `params.keys`

I obtained : `["id", "name", "infos"]`

But I want to get ALL keys, in a simple array, like : `["id", "name", "infos", "data", "signed"]`

there is a simple way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
def deep_hash_keys(h)
 h.keys + h.map { |_, v| v.is_a?(Hash) ? deep_hash_keys(v) : nil }.flatten.compact
end

params = {"id"=>23, "name"=>"test", "infos"=>{"data"=>"er323e3ee23reQir", "signed"=>true}}

deep_hash_keys(params) # => ["id", "name", "infos", "data", "signed"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a new method for it:

```
class Hash
  def all_keys
    keys = []
    each{|k,v|
      keys << k
      keys << v.all_keys if v.respond_to?(:all_keys)
    }
    keys.flatten.uniq
  end
end

params =  {"id"=>23, "name"=>"test", "infos"=>{"data"=>"er323e3ee23reQir", "signed"=>true}}

p params.all_keys
```

Advantage: You may also define a all_keys-method in Non-Hash-functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can monkey patch Hash class:

```
class Hash
  def all_keys
   keys + map { |k, v| v.is_a?(Hash) ? v.all_keys : nil }.flatten.compact
  end
end

params = {"id"=>23, "name"=>"test", "infos"=>{"data"=>"er323e3ee23reQir", "signed"=>true}}

params.all_keys # => ["id", "name", "infos", "data", "signed"]
```